# RxJS Observable: repeat using count and then using notifier

Tags: rxjs, observable, repeat

I have an Observable that emits `Either = Success | Failure`:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

type Success = { type: 'success' };
type Failure = { type: 'failure' };

type Either = Success | Failure;

const either$ = new Observable<Either>(observer => {
    console.log('subscribe');
    observer.next({ type: 'failure' });
    observer.complete();
    return () => {
        console.log('unsubscribe');
    };
});
```

I want to allow the user to "retry" the observable when the Observable completes and the last value was `Failure`.

(The `retry{,When}` operators do not help here because they work with errors on the `error` channel. For this reason, I believe we should think in terms of `repeat` instead.)

I want to:

- Repeat the Observable `n` times until the last value is not `Failure`.
- Then, allow the user to repeat manually. When a repeat notifier observable (`repeat$`) emits, repeat the observable again.

For example:

```
// subscribe
// next { type: 'failure' }
// unsubscribe

// retry 2 times:

// subscribe
// next { type: 'failure' }
// unsubscribe

// subscribe
// next { type: 'failure' }
// unsubscribe

// now, wait for repeat notifications…
// on retry notification:

// subscribe
// next { type: 'failure' }
// unsubscribe
```

Comment: I think the major flaw in this is that you want to repeat the chain manually because one `subscribe()` basically means you'll have one subscription. If you allow users to retry manually then you'll have one chain with multiple subscriptions which is not what you normally want to achieve. I think using the `window` operator it could work but I'd recommend just making new `subscribe` call on every `repeat$`

Comment: My function needs to return an `Observable`, and the subscription is created outside of my control.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't come up with something simpler, but the code does what you want.

See https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-yqcejk

```typescript
defer(() => {
   let retries = 0;

   const source = new BehaviorSubject(null);

   return merge(source, repeat$.pipe(filter(() => retries <= MAX_RETRIES)))
       .pipe(
           concatMapTo(either$),
           tap(value => {
               const action = value as Either;
               if (action.type === 'failure') {
                   if (retries < MAX_RETRIES) {
                       retries += 1;
                       source.next(null);
                   }
               } else {
                   retries = 0;
               }
           })
       )
}).subscribe(console.log);
```

I had to manually count retries.

The code has two sources of events `source` for automatic retries and `repeat$` for user retries. All events are mapped to `either$` using `concatMapTo`. As a side-effect we either `next()` to retry or do nothing waiting for user to retry.

User retries are suppressed using `filter(() => retries >= MAX_RETRIES)` until `MAX_RETRIES` count is reached.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I noticed that the `unsubscribe`s don't happen until all the retries have completed. Do you know why that is? Also, is there any reason to use `concatMapTo` over `mergeMapTo`?

Comment: `unsubscribe`s happen as last because I think the run is synchronous, you can use `observeOn(asyncScheduler)` to make it run async and then it unsubscribes exactly as in your example. As for the `concatMapTo` vs `mergeMapTo` - I've chosen `concatMapTo` because it's safer, preventing multiple `either$` Observables running at the same time...